# Unit test with mocktail in flutter using Either is getting something wrong

Tags: flutter, dart, clean-architecture

im trying to do unit test which code is

```
class SearchRepositoryMock extends Mock implements SearchRepository {}
void main() {

  `final repository = SearchRepositoryMock();
  final useCase = SearchByTextImpl(repository);
  test('should retun list of ResultSearch', () async {
    when(() => repository.search(any())).thenAnswer((_) async => const Right(<ResultSearch>[]));
    final result = await useCase("something");
    expect(result, isA<List<ResultSearch>>());
  });
}`
enter code here
```

my SearchRepository is a "interface"

```
abstract class SearchRepository {
  Future<Either<FailureSearchException, List<ResultSearch>>> search(String? searchText);
}
```

after running test im getting error [image]

i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are mocking the next response

```
 when(() => repository.search(any())).thenAnswer((_) async => const Right(<ResultSearch>[]));
```

As you can see, you are expecting a Right answer not a `<ResultSearch>[]`.

So in order to get the `List<ResultSearch>` instead the `Right<R>`, you should do something like

```
when(() => repository.search(any())).thenAnswer((_) async => const Right(<ResultSearch>[])).right;
```

Please note that you are getting the value using **.right**